# Hide/Show UITableView on Button touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton, xcode4.5, ios6.1

I Have one Screen in which i have to hide or show UITableview on button touch.
This single button have two diffrent image which is change by button click.

I had tried with this code.

```
- (void)collapseOrExpandButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
      int i = [sender.titleLabel.text intValue];

NSNumber *numb;
if(i == 0)
{
    numb = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    sender.titleLabel.text = @"1";
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    tView.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    numb = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    sender.titleLabel.text = @"0";
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    tView.hidden = NO;
}


}
```

And with this i set button manually

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *a = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 62)];
a.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.view addSubview:a];
button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 20, 30, 30)];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(collapseOrExpandButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.tag = section;


if(button.tag != section)
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.titleLabel.text = @"0";
}
else
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"]      forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.titleLabel.text = @"1";
}

[a addSubview:button];
return a;

}
```

But nothing works for me.

I also tried with Breakpoint  but it wasn't calling  my custom method.

`Help` is greatly appreciated.